# MonacaでiOSの機種を判別する方法

Tags: monaca

AndroidかiOSかは

```
if( monaca.isIOS ){}
```

のような感じで識別できますが、iOSの場合にiPhone6か5かiPadかiPad Airかなどを識別するにはどうすればいいのでしょうか？

ご存知の方いらっしゃいましたらご教示ください

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MonacaはCordovaを利用していますが、そのdeviceプラグインを利用することで機種を識別出来るはずです。[monaca翻訳ドキュメント](http://docs.monaca.mobi/3.5/ja/reference/phonegap_34/ja/device/#device-model)を参考にしてください。

記載されているように`device.model`は`iPhone7,2`(iPhone6の場合)のような値になっているのでそれに合わせて条件分岐させます。(iOSでは[参考リンク](http://theiphonewiki.com/wiki/Models)のIdentifierの値が入っているので注意してください。)